# How to pass and catch params correctly through an URL on RoR?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User and Credits Model, and a User has many Credits. On the User's profile page the are two buttons to add or remove a credit entry.

Buttons link like this:

To add:

```
href="/add_credit_to_user/<%=@user.id%>/add"
```

To remove:

```
href="/add_credit_to_user/<%=@user.id%>/remove"
```

My idea is to catch the last part of the URL to determine whether the credit should be positive or negative.

Route:

```
get 'add_credit_to_user/:id/:type', to: 'credits#new'
```

credits#new

```
 def new
   @credit = Credit.new
   @credit.user_id = params[:id]
   @type = params[:type]


   respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @credit }
   end
 end
```

This is how the form looks right now:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@credit, html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>

   <div class="form-inputs">    
     <% if current_user.try(:admin?) %><%= f.input :merchant_id, collection: Merchant.all %> <% end %>
     <%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all, label_method: :first_name,  :as => :hidden %>
     <%= f.input :amount, html: {class: "form-control required"} %>

   </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

credits#create

```
  def create
    @credit = Credit.new(params[:credit])
    @credit.assigned_by = current_user.email
    @credit.expires_on = Date.today + 3.month

   if @type == "remove"
      @credit.amount = -@credit.amount
    end


    respond_to do |format|
     if @credit.save
        format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@credit.user_id), notice: 'Credito creado exitosamente.' }
        format.json { render json: @credit, status: :created, location: @credit }
     else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @credit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
   end
```

I hit  href="/add_credit_to_user/<%=@user.id%>/remove" enter a credit into the form, push submit and dont get a negative amount. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: `@type` is not defined in the create instance so `@type == "remove"` will always be false. Also you should probably create named routes so you could use `simple_form_for @credit, url: self.send("#{@type}_credit_path",@credit)` this will call a named route of `remove_credit` or `add_credit`

Comment: Instead of `href="/add_credit_to_user/<%=@user.id%>/remove"` why not make that named path and then reference it with the path helper?

Comment: It would also be more advisable to actualle make controller actions `add_credit` and `remove_credit` thus you don't have to parse what type it is. I mean how is your form even determining the type currently?

Comment: I have tried Kirti's answer and it works for me. I am just curious about creating two new methods, two routes, etc...What would be a better practice, splitting methods or storing data on the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@type` is getting destroyed between requests. In order to maintain its value you can store in `session` as follows:

**`CreditsController#new`**

Replace

```
@type = params[:type]
```

With

```
session[:type] = params[:type]
```

---

**`CreditsController#create`**

Replace

```
if @type == "remove"
  @credit.amount = -@credit.amount
end
```

with

```
if session[:type] == "remove"
  @credit.amount = -@credit.amount
end
```

Comment: Great this works for me! Storing in the "session[]" means storing in the cache?

Comment: Glad to help. :) refer to Rails Guides documentation for sessions to get a better idea http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark